# Large JSON as local db in react native

Tags: database, react-native, local-storage

I have a large JSON file (140 MB) that is constant data that doesn't change. This data is to be searched and filtered in a list in a mobile app to be built in react native.

I have already checked realm and local-mongodb for local databases but they are not the solutions I am looking for.

What I want is to read from this file and filter on it. What ways can you recommend I do this?

Currently, I am reading the file every-time the app opens but that isn't efficient and is taking time. Any suggestions or methods?

The reason I am not using any server for this data is because of the cost that can accumulate. The aim is to make it a $0 cost app.

Answer (score 1):

How about [watermelon DB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)? It can be an another solution for you.

If you want to make $0 cost app, then Firebase `firestore` can be a solution too.